# Highcharts pdf export not working when we export all charts in one

Tags: pdf, highcharts

I have used highcharts and I have multiple charts to export as pdf. Now I want to show patterns in bar charts. I have applied it but now pdf is showing blank.

Here is my code
http://fiddle.jshell.net/vtexot2c/

Comment: It looks like pattern plugin breaks the exporting. Have you tried to use the solution like here: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/gd7bB/ ?

Comment: Yes. I tried it and is working well. Though I can't find option to set proper page size and chart size.